# How to test if a given rectangle intersects with a list of excluded areas?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have implemented `SegmentBisect` for 1D segments. Given a list of 1D segments, it constructs a data-structure that defines the excluded regions on the x-axis.

I have some difficulty to extend/use `SegmentBisect` to create a class that can fast find if a rectangle in the x-y space intersects an apriori list of rectangles.

The 1D solution take `O(log(n))` I assume it's possible to get `O(log^2(n))`

```
import bisect

class SegmentBisect():

    def isCoordExcluded(self, coordinate):
        i = self.excludedIndex(coordinate)
        try:
            return self.isExcluded[i]
        except:
            return False

    def excludedIndex(self, coordinate):
        return bisect.bisect_right(self.segmentBisect, coordinate)

    def __init__(self, lineSegments):

        lineSegments.sort(key=lambda x:min(x))
        self.segmentBisect = []
        self.isExcluded    = []
        for segment in lineSegments:
            if type(segment) == range:
                segment = range(min(segment), max(segment)+1) # to support input as range
            else: 
                segment = range(min(segment), max(segment))
            low  = min(segment) 
            high = max(segment)+1 # to include b-1 for the excluded segment:(a,b)
            lowExcluded  = self.isCoordExcluded(low)
            highExcluded = self.isCoordExcluded(high)

            if lowExcluded and highExcluded:
                continue
            elif not lowExcluded and not highExcluded:
                self.segmentBisect.extend([low, high])
                self.isExcluded.extend([False, True])
            elif lowExcluded and not highExcluded:
                idx = self.excludedIndex(low)
                self.segmentBisect[idx] = max(high,self.segmentBisect[idx])
            else:
                raise('Error while adding the segment {0} to the bisect array.'.format(range(low,high)))

import unittest
class TestSegmentBisect(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_five_segments_three_intersections(self, sbs=None):
        if not sbs:
            sbs = SegmentBisect([(20,30), (10,3), (2,6), (8,12), (50,100)])

        for i in range(-2,2):
            self.assertFalse(sbs.isCoordExcluded(i))

        for i in range(2,12):
            self.assertTrue(sbs.isCoordExcluded(i))

        for i in range(20,30):
            self.assertTrue(sbs.isCoordExcluded(i))

        for i in range(30,50):
            self.assertFalse(sbs.isCoordExcluded(i))

        for i in range(50,100):
            self.assertTrue(sbs.isCoordExcluded(i))

        for i in range(100,102):
            self.assertFalse(sbs.isCoordExcluded(i))

    def test_five_segments_three_intersections_range(self):
        sbs = SegmentBisect([range(20,30), range(3,10), range(2,6), range(8,12), range(50,100)])
        self.test_five_segments_three_intersections(sbs)

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSegmentBisect)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Comment: It appears you have working code and are mainly asking about a more efficient way to solve the same problem - that's not really a StackOverflow question, you should probably ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get opinions or ideas on a different approach

Comment: I have a 1D implementation for lines. To get 2D implementation for rectangles is more complicated.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry - you are indeed asking for some new functionality; but are you expecting people on StackOverflow to write the solution? What is the problem you need help with, or what is the specific question?

Comment: I need some help from others to think about the algorithm. How to make it `O(log^2(n))` which I think is possible.

Comment: Like I suggested in my first comment - StackOverflow isn't really the place for that discussion, especially if you don't even have a working algorithm that doesn't perform at the big-Oh level you require - but even if you did, algorithm review is more of a CodeReview topic

Comment: @Grismar this is not appropriate to codereview. I am sorry.

Comment: Not my opinion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211788/code-review-vs-stackoverflow

Comment: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/17GeometricSearch.pdf related